# Integral $\int \frac{2x^2-1}{\pm x(2x^2-1)+2x+ \sqrt{1+2x^2}} d x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Consider the indefinite integral
$$F_{\pm}(x):=\int \frac{2x^2-1}{\pm x(2x^2-1)+2x+ \sqrt{1+2x^2}} \mathbb{d} x.$$
For all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ it is
$$ F_{+}(x)=  \log(-x + \sqrt{1 + 2 x^2}).$$
But what is $F_{-}$?

*Note that numerical studies suggest that it does exist in a certain range. Math software already struggles to prove the formula for $F_{+}$.*

Comment: I don't think your answer for $F_+$ is itself correct. Check https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%282x%5E2-1%29%2F%28x%282x%5E2-1%29%2B2x%2Bsqrt%281%2B2x%5E2%29%29

With regards to $F_{-}$, that's a tough one. I'm pretty sure that you cannot solve it using any elementary function, but let's wait for other people to see.

Comment: @Fede1 It's correct, compare the expressions by using a lot of simplification.

Comment: fair enough then. With regards to $F_-$, I cannot help, sorry.

Comment: Since $y = f_-(x)$ is a rational curve, $\int y dx$ is elementary (this is probably not the simplest form, I just used a CAS):
$$\frac {34 - 2 \sqrt {17}} {68} \operatorname {arctanh} \omega_+ -
 \frac {34 + 2 \sqrt {17}} {68} \operatorname {arctanh} \omega_- - \\
 \frac {\sqrt {17}} {34} \operatorname {arctanh} \frac {4 x^2 - 5} {\sqrt {17}} -
 \frac 1 4 \ln(2 x^4 - 5 x^2 + 1), \\
\omega_{\pm} = \frac {2 x \sqrt {4 x^2 + 2} - 4 x^2 + 5 \pm \sqrt {17}}
 {\sqrt {34} \pm 3  \sqrt 2}.$$

Comment: @Maxim Nice find! Its a fairly nice formula. What CAS did you use?

Comment: @Maxim The derivative of your formula (say $y$) matches indeed with the integrand of $F_{-}$ (say $f_{-}$) in the sense that $-y(-x)=f_{-}(x)$. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I compared $-f_{-}$ accidentally. Rewriting the integrand was the key. Feel free to make this an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is $$F_\pm(x)=\int\frac{2x^2-1}{\pm x(2x^2-1)+2x+\sqrt{1+2x^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ Let $x=2t/(2-t^2)$, then $$\begin{aligned}F_+(t)&=2\int\bigg(\frac{t}{2-t^2}+\frac{1+t}{t^2+2t+2}\bigg)\,\mathrm{d}t,\\F_-(t)&=2\int\bigg(\frac{t}{t^2-2}-\frac{t^3-t^2-6t-2}{t^4-2t^3-12t^2-4t+4}\bigg)\,\mathrm{d}t.\end{aligned}$$ You can integrate $F_+$ directly: $$F_+(t)=-\log(2-t^2)+\log(t^2+2t+2)+C.$$
For $F_-$ you need only solve a quadratic equation to factor the denominator and then integrate directly: $$\begin{aligned}F_-(t)=\log(2-t^2)&+\frac{-17+\sqrt{17}}{34}\log(t^2+(\sqrt{17}-1)t+2)\\&+\frac{-17-\sqrt{17}}{34}\log(-t^2+(\sqrt{17}+1)t-2)+C.\end{aligned}$$
After this, solve a quadratic equation to get a formula for $F_\pm(x)$.

Comment: It should be $x = 2 t/(2 - t^2)$, then $2 x^2 + 1$ becomes a complete square. Also, since you chose the plus sign when simplifying $\sqrt {2 x^2 + 1}$, you have to take the minus sign in $t = (-1 \pm \sqrt {2 x^2 + 1})/x$ when doing back-substitution.